# Unable to clone using git in Linux Mint using my custom key

Tags: ssh, git

In my pc I setup a file named ~/job/ssh/config

```
Host bitbucket
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/job/ssh/rsa_key
 user git
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

and in my `~/.ssh/config`

```
~/.ssh/config 
Include /home/pcmagas/job/ssh/config
```

And the folder `~/job/ssh` has the following settings:

```
-rw------- 1 pcmagas pcmagas  191 Σεπ  15 10:57 config
-rw------- 1 pcmagas pcmagas 3414 Σεπ  15 10:45 rsa_key
-rw------- 1 pcmagas pcmagas  761 Σεπ  15 10:45 rsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 pcmagas pcmagas  419 Αυγ  28 15:32 work
-rw------- 1 pcmagas pcmagas  109 Αυγ  28 15:32 work.pub
```

By doing:

```
$ ssh bitbucket
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.
```

Also I can:

```
 ssh -i ~/job/ssh/rsa_key git@bitbucket.org
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
authenticated via ssh key.

You can use git to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled
```

I can connect to bithubket.

Firthermore by doing:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -i ~/job/ssh/rsa_key -o IdentitiesOnly=yes' git clone git@bitbucket.org:exampe/myproj.git
```

I can clone it:

```
Γίνεται κλωνοποίηση μέσα στο 'myproj'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 210004, done.
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
```

But I cannot without the variable. Any ideas what's wrong?

As a means of mitigation I also tried to comment the inclide line in ~/.ssh/config and placing these stuff in to `~/.ssh/config` directly:

```
Host bitbucket
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/job/ssh/rsa_key
 user git
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Furthermore I've run these commands as well:

```
chmod 400 ~/job/ssh/*
chmod +w ~/job/ssh/config
```

Comment: 1. Your keyfile is not in the default location (`~/.ssh/`) so it's not picked up by `ssh` ( and `git` by extension) itself without you specifying it's path 2. You appear to not be running an instance of `ssh-agent` with your key loaded 3. You could workaround the variable by using `git config core.sshCommand`.

Comment: But what is the point if hgaving a ssh config if I cannot specify the key into other directory.

Answer (score 0):

In order for this setting to work rename the entry:

```
Host bitbucket
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/job/ssh/rsa_key
 user git
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

Into:

```
Host bitbucket.org
 HostName bitbucket.org
 IdentityFile ~/job/ssh/rsa_key
 user git
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

This will trick the ssh-agent to use the key located upon `~/job/ssh/rsa_key` instead of the ones located into `~/.ssh`.

---

## But I have seperate config file

This works both if the entry is in:

- ~/job/ssh/config
- ~/.ssh

For the first to work you must place the line:

```
Include /home/pcmagas/job/ssh/config
```

At `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: I don't think ssh-agent is going to be involved here unless you use `AddKeysToAgent`. By specifying `IdentitiesOnly`, you're explicitly telling SSH to ignore the keys available via the agent.

Comment: But in my case worked regardless if keys in ssh-agent or not.

Comment: Eh? Of course it will work, because you are **explicitly** telling it to ignore keys in ssh-agent.